# IllegalStateException error in android fragment

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-timer

I am using CountDownTimer in fragment
Sometimes onFinish () throws an error

Attach error messages and error codes

```
public void onFinish()
{
    btnTimerStart.setText(getString(R.string.btn_restart));
    timer_display.setTextSize(45);
    timer_display.setText(getString(R.string.btn_complete));
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext (Fragment.java:696)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java:760)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString (Fragment.java:782)
  at com.sinwho.timer.TimerFragment$11.onFinish (TimerFragment.java:751)
  at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage (CountDownTimer.java:127)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was your `getString()` method is unable to get the `context`. Give them context using `getActivity()`. Try this:

```
public void onFinish()
{
    btnTimerStart.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.btn_restart));
    timer_display.setTextSize(45);
    timer_display.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.btn_complete));
}
```

Hope your problem will be solved.